# count() on filter chains in Django

Tags: python, django

When chaining filters in Django, what is the most efficient way of counting the resulting records from an individual filter? Without running the filter twice that is.

i.e.

```
 results = my_model.objects.all() 
 for filter in my_filters:
      results = results.filter(filter.get_filter_string())
      individual_num_records_affected = my_model.objects.filter(filter.get_filter_string())
```

Comment: Can you define "efficient"? Give an idea of how many rows you're dealing with? What's efficient for 50 rows might not be for 10 million. It also depends on what data you will use after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Since you just need the number of results at each step, its more efficient to use [`.count()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count) on the querysets.**

From the [`querysets` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated):

> Note: If you only need to determine the number of records in the set
>   (and don’t need the actual objects), it’s **much more efficient to
>   handle a count at the database level** using SQL’s `SELECT COUNT(*)`.
>   Django provides a `count()` method for precisely this reason.

You should not use `.len()` as it will load all of the record into Python objects and calls `len()` on the result which you don't need. You just need the number of records and `.count()` would be the better option.

Also, remember that **querysets are evaluated lazy**.

> Internally, a QuerySet can be constructed, filtered, sliced, and
>   generally passed around without actually hitting the database. No
>   database activity actually occurs until you do something to evaluate
>   the queryset.

So, until you try to use the results of the queryset, the queryset will not be evaluated i.e. no database hit will occur.

The statement `results = results.filter(filter.get_filter_string())` will not hit the database until you try to use the `results`. **You can do [`.filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#filter) on a queryset multiple times but until you don't use it, there would be no database hit.**